# How to use template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two very similar classes

Their function name are exactly same

In another method,I called them and their functions and I want my    code more concise

So I use template

Like this:

```
void method()
{
   if(...)
   {
     classA *a = new classA;
     a.f1();    
     a.f2();
     ...
   }
   else if(...)
   {
     classB *b = new classB;
     b.f1();
     b.f2();
     ...
   }
}

//It doesn't work
void method()
{
   if(...)
   {
     classA *a = new classA;
     common(a);
   }
   else if(...)
   {
     classB *b = new classB;
     common(b);
   }
}
template <class T>
void common(T &t)
{
   t.f1();  //the complier doesn't know about t
   t.f2();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your code together with the error message. The code you posted is bogus code. The second `method` is an inifinite recursion and the template `common` isnt called anywhere

Comment: Sorry about that,I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might transform

```
void method()
{
   if (...)
   {
     classA* a = new classA;
     a->f1();    
     a->f2();
     // ...
   }
   else if (...)
   {
     classB* b = new classB;
     b->f1();
     b->f2();
     // ...
   }
}
```

into

```
template <class T>
void common(T* t)
{
   t->f1();
   t->f2();
   // ...
}

void method()
{
   if (...)
   {
     classA* a = new classA;
     common(a);
   }
   else if(...)
   {
     classB* b = new classB;
     common(b);
   }
}
```

Comment: why not fix the leaks? or at least mention them ... well, `...` might handle it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Qt's memory model is "strange" (parent might be passed in constructor, with ownership transfer) :-/ so it is not necessary leak.

Comment: IOW, in your example code, you declare `common` **after** you use it. That won't work. It's not even a template problem, that would fail for any function. This answer defines `common` first, and only then uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function template is fine:

```
template <class T>
void common(T& t)
{
   t.f1(); // the complier doesn't know about t
   t.f2();
}
```

And the compiler *will* know about t when you use the function with an argument that is either a classA or a classB object.

Here's an example:

https://replit.com/@ellingb/Template-example